# join tables and return multiple rows with same main id as single rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables need to join and then the multiple row result with the same crb_pi_id from table2, will combine and return as single rows. it is possible? I used that result on printable report.

Thanks in advance.

**table1 :**

```
crb_pi_id,name,tel_no
1,john,1111111
2,paul,2222222
```

**table2 :**

```
crb_pd_id,crb_pi_id,account_name,amount
1,1,salary,500
2,1,utilities,800
3,2,transportation,300
```

**result** should

```
name,salary,utilities,trasportation

john,500,800,0
paul,0,0,300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, a.tel_no, sum(b.amount) as totamount

from table1 a left outer join table2 b on a.crb_pi_id = b.crb_pi_id
group by a.name, a.tel_no
```

You'll have to include whatever fields from table1 that you list in the select in the group statement

Comment: hi raj, I want to combine multiple rows output in a single rows but should display the field in different column.

Answer (score 0):

not sure you can really do that w/ straight sql aside from using a cursor and a temp variable being assigned the values of each cell value successively. or if you can use a higher level language you can use php's combination of implode() and string concat on the array from your query call.

edit 1: oh never mind... the question changed right after i posted my answer haha

edit 2: perhaps you wanted something like this? (untested pseudo)

```
select
    t1.name,
    case when (t2.crb_pi = t1.crb_pi) and (t2.account_name = 'salary') then t2.amount else 0 end as 'salary'
    case when (t2.crb_pi = t1.crb_pi) and (t2.account_name = 'utilities') then t2.amount else 0 end as 'utilities'
    case when (t2.crb_pi = t1.crb_pi) and (t2.account_name = 'transportation') then t2.amount else 0 end as 'transportation'    
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t2.crb_pi = t1.crb_pi
```

Comment: sorry for repeated reediting and undelete. new to this site, still figuring out how to do stuff with the response & comments and stuff :)

Comment: hi alien,I tried your code but the output still multiple rows. here is the code I used base on your suggestion     select
    t1.name,
    case when (t2.crb_pi_id = t1.crb_pi_id) and (t2.account_code = 'salary') then t2.amount else 0 end as 'salary',
    case when (t2.crb_pi_id = t1.crb_pi_id) and (t2.account_code = 'utilities') then t2.amount else 0 end as 'utilities',
    case when (t2.crb_pi_id = t1.crb_pi_id) and (t2.account_code = 'trasportation') then t2.amount else 0 end as 'trasportation'   
from crb_personal_info t1
left join crb_personal_details t2
    on t2.crb_pi_id = t1.crb_pi_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use with clause here and then group the results accordingly

```
select t1.name 'name', t2.amount 'salary',
CASE WHEN t2.crb_pi_id=t1.crb_pi_id and t2.crb_pd_id=2 then t2.amount ELSE 0 END 'utilities',
CASE WHEN t2.crb_pi_id=t1.crb_pi_id and t2.crb_pd_id=3 then t2.amount ELSE 0 END 'trans'
into #t3
from #t1 t1 inner join #t2 t2 on t1.crb_pi_id=t2.crb_pi_id

select name, max(salary), max(utilities), max(trans)
from t3
group by name
```

Comment: hi anil,Itried your code but there was an error saying (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WITH t3(name , salary , utilities) as
(
select t1.name, t2.amount 'salary',
C' at line 1 )

Comment: My mistake.. mySQL does not support WITH clause. So you can use a temporary table instead. I have edited my post. #t1 and #t2 represent your two tables